# Every sub-annotation in the .owl file has an 'rdf:type' and its IRI along with it

Tags: annotations, ontology, protege

An .owl file obtained by merging individual .owl files has an extra sub-annotation of 'rdf:type' coming along with every sub-annotation that was given. The IRI is also visible with this annotation. This extra sub-annotation is not able to be deleted as well. I have no idea how this issue came. Please help me to remove this unwanted annotation.

[image: Screenshot of the extra annotation]

I tried to delete this sub-annotation but the sub-annotation that was required was also deleted with it. Also tried to remove it using Notepad++ but unable to find it.

Comment: Can you share the owl file?